# componentsSeparatedByString return 1 object when string is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

I convert string into array by componentsSeparatedByString. It return array perfect. but when string is empty return 1 object.

why this happen ?

```
NSMutableArray *imagesList=[[[productDetail objectForKey:@"productImage"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]mutableCopy];
```

Comment: And what do you want it to return in that case?

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr 0 object.

Comment: i want to know why this happen ?

Comment: Well, then you are mistaking in your expectations. You have one string. You divide it into components. How can you have less than one component? Empty string - `@""` - is still NSString object.

Comment: If you're looking for alto that causing this behaviour, it can be something like this (pseudo code) `for (nextChar in string) {
       if (nextChar is ',') { array.add(accString); accString = "" }
       else { accString.append(nextChar) }
    }
array.add(accString)`

As you can see in case of string without ',' (and empty string) it will return the whole string as the only component.

Comment: Can you tell for what purpose do you use it and what are you intensions? Maybe, I can help you

Comment: First `NSLog` whats there in `[productDetail objectForKey:@"productImage"]` and mention the same in question portion. It will help us to identify the cause of issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because, you are passing empty string("") and `componentsSeparatedByString` is trying to separate your string by comma(,) but their is no comma(,) in your string so it is returning 1 array item(that is "").

```
NSMutableArray *imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
if(![productDetail isEqualToString:@""]) {   
    imagesList=[[[productDetail objectForKey:@"productImage"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the delimiter is not found in string, the original string is returned in the array.